# How to build a queue for sign up like the Mailbox app?

Tags: ios

I've searched to try and find the answer, and maybe it's very obvious, but I haven't been able to find it.

Could anyone shed some light on how to go about building a user sign up queue like Mailbox did for the launch of their iOS app?

Image of what I mean

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You would need some kind of backend (database) to keep track of the users and their positions in line. This would be external to the app itself.

Comment: @IsaacDrachman is Correct. This screen is reading from a backend API that shows how many users are ahead of you. If you're new to iOS networking in general, I suggest looking at this tutorial for AFNetworking framework to get you started. This won't help you for making a backend API though. http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial